# How to add a single file to GIT LFS?

Tags: git, git-lfs

How can I add just a single file to GIT LFS?

Most examples show adding a pattern that specifies which files to add to LFS. However, I wish to add single file. If, for example, I do

```bash
git lfs track "file.bin"
```

this will track *all* files named `file.bin` regardless of what directory they are in.

I considered adding an exclusion filter (`!` pattern) to `.gitattributes` so exclude all directories but that is not supported.

The best I've done so far is to track the file pattern for the file I want to add, add the file and then remove the tracking of that file pattern. This is a little fiddly. Is there a better way?

I want to express the file pattern `$ROOT_OF_GIT_REPO/file.bin` but am lacking a way to express the `$ROOT_OF_GIT_REPO` part.

Answer (score 46):

Use:

`git lfs track --filename [file path]`

Source: `git lfs track --help`

> --filename
>
> Treat the arguments as literal filenames, not as patterns. Any special glob
> characters in the filename will be escaped when writing the .gitattributes
> file.

This option has been available since v2.9.0 of the LFS extension ([pull request](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/3756)). You can check your local version: `git lfs version`.

Comment: this is possibly a newish option, as I get `Error: unknown flag: --filename Sorry, no usage text found for "track"` with git version 2.17.1

Comment: This has more to do with the version of the LFS extension: `git lfs version`.

Comment: it seems like this should be the preferred answer to me

Comment: Does this approach also work with `git lfs migrate import`?

Answer (score 24):

Include the path to the file, instead of just the filename.

Comment: How can I specify a path of a file that's in the root directory of the repository?

Comment: With a slash.  `/file.txt`

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work. The file pattern `/file.bin` matches any file named `file.bin` including in sub directories. I feel I need a special character to mark that the file pattern should start with the root of the GIT repo

Comment: @user2746401 : No, it doesn't.  Not according to the docs, and not according to my tests (which I just repeated yet again in response to your comment, with the same result).  The "special character"  you need to know is `/`.

Comment: Which versions of Git and Git LFS are you using? I'm afraid /file.txt still matches more broadly. Can you point me towards the doc on `/`?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore - "A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, '/*.c' matches 'cat-file.c' but not 'mozilla-sha1/sha1.c'."

Comment: Oh, and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes - "The rules by which the pattern matches paths are the same as in .gitignore files (see gitignore[5]), with a few exceptions..."  (Don't worry, the exceptions don't affect what we're talking about.)

Comment: I suggest you post what observation is it that makes you think this information is incorrect, because it's far more likely that you've drawn conclusions from a misleading observation than that the git docs (and repeated tests to verify the behavior) are wrong.

Comment: I played around a little more and it was my incorrect observations. @Mark Adelsberger thanks for sticking with the question! Could you add your comment to your answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Remember to put (.extension type) too

Answer (score 9):

You can specify any filename or path in your repository. You aren't limited to using file extensions. You could also track a specific directory with git lfs track 'assets/*' or an entire directory tree with git lfs track 'assets/**/*'. You could also track individual files specifically with git lfs track path/to/file which will track only that file.